# Promise Javascript wixsite

Tags: javascript, node.js

Eu to pegando javascript a uns 3 dias por isso sou muito leigo, eu manjo de java e c# um pouco. Estou fazendo um site no wix usando o propio backend deles que é em js. Pelo que eu entendi js executa o código de maneira síncrona, e por conta disso estou muito perdido. Não consigo entender como fazer executar na ordem que eu quero. Ai eu achei um negocio chamado Promise que parece fazer isso, só que não to conseguindo entender.

```
function atualizarBarraDeMembro  () {
console.log("Atualizando Barra de Membro...");
let icone = $w('#imgIcone');
let invocador = $w('#txtInvocador');
let essencia = $w('#txtValor');
let lg;
logado(local.getItem("invocador"),local.getItem("senha")).then((l) => {
    console.log("na promise(logado): "+l);
    return new Promise(() => {
        lg = l;
    });
}).then(() => {
    return getMembro(local.getItem("invocador"), local.getItem("senha"));
}).then((membro) => {
    return new Promise(() =>{
        if (lg) {
            console.log("membro: "+membro);
            icone.src =membro.icone;
            invocador.text = membro.invocador;
            essencia.text = membro.essencia;
            console.log(membro.icone);
            console.log(membro.invocador);
            console.log(membro.essencia);
        }
    })
}).then(() => {
    console.log("Barra de Membro Atualizada!");
});
```

}

Comment: A função logado executa normalmente mas os then's depois dela são todos ignorados.

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite amigo,

Toda promessa precisa ser resolvida antes que o Then possa ser acionado, no caso somente ficou faltante o  `resolve()` no seu código para indicar que a promessa foi cumprida e então seguir os outros passos.

```
function atualizarBarraDeMembro  () {
console.log("Atualizando Barra de Membro...");
let icone = $w('#imgIcone');
let invocador = $w('#txtInvocador');
let essencia = $w('#txtValor');
let lg;
logado(local.getItem("invocador"),local.getItem("senha")).then((l) => {
    console.log("na promise(logado): "+l);
    return new Promise((resolve) => { //Lembrar de adicionar resolve no método para marcar a promessa como resolvida posteriormente
        lg = l;
        resolve() // <-- adicionar retorno aqui caso necessário
    });
}).then(() => {
    return getMembro(local.getItem("invocador"), local.getItem("senha"));
}).then((membro) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) =>{
        if (lg) {
            console.log("membro: "+membro);
            icone.src =membro.icone;
            invocador.text = membro.invocador;
            essencia.text = membro.essencia;
            console.log(membro.icone);
            console.log(membro.invocador);
            console.log(membro.essencia);
            resolve()
        }
    })
}).then(() => {
    console.log("Barra de Membro Atualizada!");
```

Nesse tipo de situação por favor coloque o código completo no github ou em algum outro meio para que possamos te ajudar de forma mais fácil, tive que fazer Mock de todas as funções que você deixou fora do arquivo para testar.

Recomendo muito a leitura sobre Promisses descrita no site oficial da mozilla para aprofundar um pouco mais os conhecimentos.

Fonte: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise